# Proof of one side or question on the other, talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara

A boy asked me today:
How does the gemora choose if to use something as a proof to one side or as a question on the other?

The example he brought was:

Of a question:    [Kiddushin 63b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.63b.7)

> **תנן** רצו אחד נותן גט ואחד כונס תיובתא דרב אמר לך רב שאני התם דכיון דאיכא אחר בהדיה אירתותי מירתת

Of a proof: [Ibid](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.63b.8)

> תניא **כוותיה** דרב אסי

Please help me find the answer

Comment: The gemara sometimes has two versions, one where it was asked as a question, and the other where it is brought as a proof.  At the end of the day, they amount to the same thing, which is that an additional source supports one side, and not the other.

Comment: Thank you @רבותמחשבות i understand that but i thought their might be some reason behind it to

Comment: A good example of this is [Kesubos 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.9b?lang=bi) where the gemarra first brings a Mishnah as support for a teaching by saying אף אנן נמי תנינא, and then a few lines later asks a question (because this teaching already appears in a Mishnah) by saying מאי קמ"ל תנינא

Comment: See https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=26156

Comment: One example: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47796/170

Comment: @רבותמחשבות The mavo of R. Shmuel Hanagid lists asking a question on one side and bringing a proof to one side as separate categories.

Comment: Maybe the answer is the gemora always trys to first ask a question, and to give the other party the opertunity to clarify his possision (by answering the question) but when it seems that there is no posiblitly for the other side to answer, then they bring it as a proof of the first side. what do you think?

Comment: My example precludes what you wrote.